# pcregrep recursive, show surrounding lines

Tags: grep

I know how to do it with grep but now pcregrep. I tried:

```
 pcregrep -M -1 -rl '."\n' 2012 -name en*.txt
```

but it doesn't work?

Basically I want it to show one line ahead and one line below in all files that have the name en_blahblahblah.txt recursively in folder 2012. But I tried that command and it doesn't work.
I need to use pcregrep because grep doesn't support newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-A lines` and `-B lines` option.

```
[aman@aman test]$ pcregrep -M -B 2 -A 2 "C\nD" temp 
And failed to add the T and M;      Another called my grammar vile

C
D
                    And criticized my writing style.
Each day I scan each Subject line
```

From the man page

> ```
>    -A number, --after-context=number
>              Output  number  lines of context after each matching line.
>
>
>    -B number, --before-context=number
>              Output  number lines of context before each matching line.
> ```

Comment: I tried `pcregrep -M -B 2 -A 2 '.\n"' 11` and it doesn't work for me

Comment: @JOHANNES_NYÅTT I posted it after testing. Can you supply some sample input and expected output?